# Recuperar Valor BBDD para que salga marcado en un radio button

Tags: vue.js, radiobutton

Estoy realizando una aplicación en vue y ahora tengo la siguiente duda como puedo recuperar el valor introducido en la BBDD y que este salga en un radiobutton cuando se edita el formulario.
Lo he intentado y no consigo que salga chequeado el radio button, si pongo un input test si que sale el valor.

```
<div class="input-group-text">
                                <input type="radio" name="activo" id="rsn" aria-label="S/N" :value="tabla.valor"/>S/N
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <input type="radio" name="activo" id="rsi" aria-label="si" :value="tabla.valor"/>Si
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <input type="radio" name="activo" id="rno" aria-label="no" :value="tabla.valor"/>No
                            </div>
```

¿ Ha alguieb se le ocurre alguna idea ?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes una aplicación:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { tabla: { valor : 'Si' } }
});

<div id="app">
  <div class="input-group-text">
    <input type="radio" name="activo" id="rsn" aria-label="S/N" value="S/N" :checked="tabla.valor == 'S/N'"/>S/N
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-text">
    <input type="radio" name="activo" id="rsi" aria-label="si" value="Si" :checked="tabla.valor == 'Si'"/>Si
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-text">
    <input type="radio" name="activo" id="rno" aria-label="no" value="No" :checked="tabla.valor == 'No'"/>No
  </div>
</div>
```

Cambia `:value="tabla.valor"` en `value="S/N"` y agréga `:checked="tabla.valor == 'S/N'"`.

Un exemplo esta aqi: https://jsfiddle.net/h2jpe0b3/

Comment: Hola Ivan, gracias funciona perfectamente.